# citelist with institution

Tags: biblatex

I use biblatex with `maxcitenames = 2`.

Now I would like to reference the list `institution` (consists of 3 institutions separated with `and`). The command `citelist{key}{institution}` gives me the first institution and then an "et al.", as it does for authors.

Is there a way to get the entire entry when using `citelist{key}{institution}`?

Best
Christian

Comment: Mhhh, can you provide a full MWE? I just checked with a short example and got all three institutions with `maxcitenames=2`. Maybe you have a `maxitems=1` (or similar) loitering around somewhere; try to pass `maxitems=999` to `biblatex` in the loading-time options (according to [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) `maxitems` can even be set on a per-type and per-entry basis).

Comment: `maxitems` is an option though that should also apply to the bibliography as well, so if it were set to `1` you should also see only one institution in the bibliography.

Answer (score 1):

`maxitems=999` worked fine! Thank you..